# iTunes doesn't list my apps

Tags: itunes, iphone

I'm not sure if this is normal but I've never been able to list all my apps in itunes.  As you can see, the list is completely empty.  This has been for the last few years and on different computers with the most updated itunes.  Any ideas if this is  normal?

[image]

Comment: On the list scroll up or down, there are to three scrollable areas in that screen (one on the left, one in the middle (which is hard to find), and one on the right)

Answer (score 4):

It's funny, but have you tried to scroll the page?

The first block of apps is empty, but apps that support file sharing is in another block at the bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking at is the list of apps downloaded onto your computer.  It appears that you don't have anything saved to your computer.

You can easily [redownload your past purchases](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201272#apps).

Comment: He is looking for the apps on his iPhone not his computer

Comment: The list that you uploaded is the list of saved apps on the computer.  To the right is the list of home screens where you can rearrange the icons for the apps, but you can't do anything more than rearrange and delete apps there.

Comment: It is also a list of apps on his phone, next to each app should be an "Install" or "Remove" button which shows that they are In fact also showing ones on the phone

Comment: Follow the link I posted and download a single app.  Then you'll see those buttons.  I have only 4 apps downloaded to my computer and this is what I see, yet it also saying my phone has 191 apps installed.  http://i.imgur.com/UxSTbme.jpg

Comment: Oh, I see all my phone apps and a transfer button...

Answer (score 1):

Only the apps that you download on your PC or Mac will be displayed there.

As you can see in the image, I have many apps installed on my iPhone on the right side (home screen section), but only one app is shown on the left in the apps list (this is the app that I have downloaded on my PC).

So you'll have to download all the apps on your Mac/PC for them to show in the list.[image]